# (Mis)Understanding solving ordinary differential equations?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

So I am learning ordinary differential equations theory and I have come across the Fredholm alternative and kernel solutions to ODEs. And I have started to think my understanding of how integrals and differentials work is somewhat flawed and needs some rethinking. Here is my problem:

Suppose we are trying to solve the problem
$$x''(t) = x(t)$$
subject to $$x(a)=0, x'(a)=0$$
Simple enough, from standard trick of solving DEs, we know $$x=c_1e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$$ solving for $c_1$, $c_2$ is trivial.

But now I run into Fredholm.

Fredholm says, integrate both sides of the equation from $a$ to $t$.
$$x'(t) - x'(a)= \int  _{a}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau \implies x'(t) = \int  _{a}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau$$
Good so far. Now, I look at the RHS of the above equation and I say that
$$F(t) = \int  _{a}^{t} x(\tau) d\tau$$
So,
$$x'(t) = F(t)$$
Straight out of an undergraduate engineering education, I would say
$$x = \int_{a}^t F(t) dt$$
But Fredholm says
$$x(t) = \int_{a}^{s} \int_{a}^t x(\tau) d\tau ds$$ and not
$$x(t) = \int_{a}^{t} \int_{a}^t x(\tau) d\tau ds$$
This is the part that bothers me. Why are the limits going from $a$ to $s$? Shouldn't it be $a$ to $t$, since $x$ is a function of $t$? Isn't $s$ just some dummy variable, with no connection to $t$? Because I know it is bad practice writing
$$I = \int_{a}^{x} f(x) dx$$ because $x$ is a dummy variable and it's more rigorous to write that integral as $$I = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$
But that is about the extent of my knowledge regarding mathematical formalisms.
Furthermore, he claims that we can switch order of integration, and say
$$x(t) = \int_{a}^{t} \left(\int_{a}^s  ds \right) x(\tau) d\tau$$
and then I'd expect it to say $$ \int_{a}^s  ds  = (s-a)$$ but no, that integral is actually equal to $\tau - t$, and the final equation looks like
$$x(t) = \int_{a}^{t} (\tau - t) x(\tau) d\tau$$
How? Why is this allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
            x''(t)=x(t),\;\;\; x(a)=x'(a)=0.
$$
Integrate twice and apply $x(a)=x'(a)=0$, and use $x''(t)=x$ at the end:
\begin{align}
         x(t)&=x(t)-x(a) \\
               & =\int_a^t x'(u)du \\
               & =\int_a^t (x'(u)-x'(a))du \\
               & =\int_a^t\int_a^ux''(v)dvdu \\
               & = -\int_a^t\left[\frac{d}{du}(t-u)\right]\left[\int_a^u x''(v)dv\right] du \\
              & = \int_a^t(t-u) \frac{d}{du}\int_a^u x''(v)dv \\
              & =\int_a^t(t-u)x''(u)du \\
              & =\int_a^t(t-u)x(u)du
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, it is mostly a clever mathematical simplification?

Comment: @megamence : Basically. It's the type of thing you get used to when dealing with such equations. There's a pattern there, and a method to the madness.

Comment: and I assume this can be done for all sorts of boundary conditions?

Comment: @megamence: Yes. In this case I am using the solutions of $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$ to satisfy $0$ endpoint conditions. That's the operator you started with.

Comment: @megamence: You can accept this accept by pressing the check mark to the left of my answer. You can +1 it if you want as well. If you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: so I have a quick question: if I have the equation $y''=f(x)$, naive me would have said "integrate it twice wrt x", and would have written $y = \int_{a}^x \int_{a}^x f(x) dx dx$. Was this bad notation to begin with? 
Also, was the right way of writing the integrals $y = \int_{a}^x \int_{a}^v f(u) du dv$ always this?

Comment: @megamence : $\int_a^x \int_a^x f(x)dxdx$ is not good notation. You have over-used $x$ to where it is not clear what is going on.

Comment: I see. Do you have a resource on how to convert double integrals to convolution integrals?

Comment: @megamence : Just make sure you're using consistent notation $\int_a^x \int_a^y f(z)dz dy$ for example. If you use that notation, then you can interchanges orders of integration and get the same thing. The integration region is over a triangle.